# Extract part of string starts from ~ for all rows in specific column in data frame

Tags: r, dataframe

I have the following data set:

```
          Category                                             Term Count
1 GOTERM_MF_DIRECT                      GO:0005102~receptor binding     3
2 GOTERM_MF_DIRECT GO:0008139~nuclear localization sequence binding     2
3 GOTERM_CC_DIRECT        GO:0016021~integral component of membrane     9
4 GOTERM_CC_DIRECT                         GO:0071564~npBAF complex     3
```

I want to keep the MF/CC in the first column and extract the string starting from "~" (to exclude GO:001..) in the third column. I can do it using loops but is there an elegant way to achieve what I need?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  mutate(Category = substr(Category, 8,9), 
         Term = stringr::str_remove(Term, "(.*?)~"))
```

**Output**:

```
  Category Term                                  Count
  <chr>    <chr>                                 <dbl>
1 MF       receptor binding                          3
2 MF       nuclear localization sequence binding     2
3 CC       integral component of membrane            9
4 CC       npBAF complex                             3
```

**Data**:

```
df <- tibble::tribble(
  ~Category, ~Term, ~Count,
  "GOTERM_MF_DIRECT", "GO:0005102~receptor binding", 3,
  "GOTERM_MF_DIRECT", "GO:0008139~nuclear localization sequence binding", 2,
  "GOTERM_CC_DIRECT", "GO:0016021~integral component of membrane", 9,
  "GOTERM_CC_DIRECT", "GO:0071564~npBAF complex", 3
)
```